# allow touch control up and down in aframe

Tags: mobile, controls, touch, aframe

touch control in aframe scene works only in the left and right, it does not work up and down using a mobile
however using the desktop it works perfectly
when I added touch control, look control is removed

how to add both of them at the same time

Answer (score 3):

I wanted the same thing on mobile. Add this code after you load the aFrame library:

```
AFRAME.components["look-controls"].Component.prototype.onTouchMove = function (t) {
                        var PI_2 = Math.PI/2,
                        e,
                        o = this.el.sceneEl.canvas,
                        i = this.yawObject,
                        j = this.pitchObject;
                        this.touchStarted && this.data.touchEnabled && (e = 2 * Math.PI * (t.touches[0].pageX - this.touchStart.x) / o.clientWidth, f = 2 * Math.PI * (t.touches[0].pageY - this.touchStart.y) / o.clientHeight, j.rotation.x += .3 * f, i.rotation.y += .5 * e, j.rotation.x = Math.max(-PI_2, Math.min(PI_2, j.rotation.x)), this.touchStart = {
                                x: t.touches[0].pageX,
                                y: t.touches[0].pageY
                            })
                        }
```

Or, alternatively, you can find the code for "look-controls" in the aframe.min.js(or whichever file you use) and modify onTouchMove function there.

Answer (score 2):

I took the answer from 'Igor R' and cleaned it a little bit up.

```
AFRAME.components["look-controls"].Component.prototype.onTouchMove = function (t) {
    if (this.touchStarted && this.data.touchEnabled) {
        this.pitchObject.rotation.x += .6 * Math.PI * (t.touches[0].pageY - this.touchStart.y) / this.el.sceneEl.canvas.clientHeight;
        this.yawObject.rotation.y += /*  */ Math.PI * (t.touches[0].pageX - this.touchStart.x) / this.el.sceneEl.canvas.clientWidth;
        this.pitchObject.rotation.x = Math.max(Math.PI / -2, Math.min(Math.PI / 2, this.pitchObject.rotation.x));
        this.touchStart = {
            x: t.touches[0].pageX,
            y: t.touches[0].pageY
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please specify if you are using an iOS device or an Android. Steps to follow:

1. On iOS 12.2 it is a known issue as Apple has disabled deviceorientation and device motion in Safari.  Tried to manually enable it but still doesn't work.  Installed Chrome and cardboard-vr files but no fruitful results.
2. On Android, install google cardboard, if you don't have it.  Update the version of the Aframe, make sure you are on A-Frame 0.9.2.